# How to recognize some parts of the terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I created an island and want to check when I reach the island.
How can I add a tag to the island? The island built from a set height of the terrain.
I added a picture for better understanding:

Comment: Why dont use a collider which detects when you enter in the island?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can bound your island using invisible cubes with colliders as triggers.
2. You can detect a terrain texture and check if a current texture equals an island's texture - detecting a terrain texture is at a following link: [detecting terrain texture](https://forum.unity.com/threads/detecting-terrain-texture-at-position.94723/)